# Different output, same username and password

Tags: .htpasswd

I was wondering why even for the same username and the same password, htpasswd outputs a new hash everytime? I tried finding an answer to this question, but couldn't.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The passwords generated by "htpasswd" use a random salt, to make it harder to guess.  It also means that pre-crypted dictionaries for attacks have to be much larger since they have to crypt every possible password with every possible salt.

htpasswd uses [crypt(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/crypt) behind the scenes.

Comment: Thanks. I was not aware of the random salt.

Comment: `passwd`, the Unix password changing utility does the same thing.  (Although these days, many of them do MD5 passwords instead of crypt, so there isn't a salt.)

Comment: In case you're wondering, "How does the server determine the salt if the salt was randomly generated?"...  the salt is the first two characters of the `crypt()` output.

Comment: @DemPilafian Thanks for the salt point! But, actually, it's not the first two characters; instead, the output of `crypt` has a format of `$<HASH_TYPE>$<SALT>$<HASH_VALUE>`. And hence the server can parse this string and get the hash salt.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tip for you, when generating secret keys or strings, use a one_way_hash( salt + current time), these are, if not impossible, hard to crack. I normally employ this to create tokens or session keys.